# RELATIVE TIME EXPRESSIONS + で

Tags: grammar, nuances

> A) 休みは**明日で**終わります。
>
> > The vacation will be over tomorrow.

> B) 彼がこの家を買ってから**今年で**四年になります。
>
> > It's been four years this year since he bought this house.

Would the meaning change at all if we got rid of で?

One of my books says the following:

[image: img1]

There are no examples using relative expressions such as 明日 or 今年: that's why the book as talks about に. I suppose it's the same idea, right?

Comment: See these two answers: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/62192/30454 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/84192/30454